# Send file logs to logstash

Tags: logstash

I have files in GCS, each file contains json lines
file example:

```
{"msg": "hello world", "level": "info", "timestamp": "2017-09-01T00:00"}
{"msg": "some error",  "level": "error", "timestamp": "2017-09-02T00:00"}
{"msg": "success" , "level": "info", "timestamp": "2017-09-03T00:00"}
...
```

I am running on all files in GCS, downloading each file and Im trying to send them to logstash - so I get each line of log in elastic

here is my logstash conf:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "xxxxxxx"
    index => "app-log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

now how do I send the file contents to logstash?
should I use a different input than tcp? maybe filebeat? 
is there any demo code in nodejs (or other language) to send the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using the `http` plugin

```
input { 
  http { codec => line} 
}

filter {
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://xxxxx.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "xxxxxxx"
    index => "app"
  }

}
```

and then sending with http:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/ \
  -H 'content-type: content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{"msg": "hello world", "level": "info", "timestamp": "2017-09-01T00:00"}
{"msg": "some error",  "level": "error", "timestamp": "2017-09-02T00:00"}
{"msg": "success" , "level": "info", "timestamp": "2017-09-03T00:00"}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading and then sending logs to `logstash`  use [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) which will even work for future changes in file by sending them to `logstash` and on top of all that it's very easy to setup and integrates very well with `logstash` and `elaticsearch`.

Comment: is there way for me to send the log file without saving it locally? I want to send the content of the file downloaded from GCS by my script to logstash WO saving it locally - since it is a huge amount of files, how can I do that?

Comment: @dina looks like right now directly parsing files from S3 is possible but GCS is not supported yet. You can see all available input plugins [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html). But you may try to process those files as plain files using [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) which may not work also if not this works out definitely you can insert all those files to S3 for processing and then from S3 without any processing can insert into ELK.

Comment: @dina let me know if this works out for you update answer if this is what you are looking

Comment: thanks for your help, I havnt tried the `file input plugin` , I ended using the `http` plugin, thanks anyways